# C# I want to use either a switch or if statement to select a sorting algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, switch-statement, mapping

I am writing a program that will take user input and run it through whichever type of sort they choose. If I try to use a switch I cannot figure out how to add arguments to a switch or if I use an if statement how do I implement that with the user's input?

Here is the code and thank you all for your help.

```
using System;

namespace ASortAboveTheRest
{
    internal class Program        
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainMenu();
        }

        static void MainMenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose a sort algorithm to perform on the Array");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 1: Heap Sort");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 2: Bubble Sort");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 3: Shell Sort");

            Console.WriteLine("Please type: 1, 2, or 3");
            string myOption;
            myOption = Console.ReadLine();
            int[] arr = new int[10];
            int i;
            Console.Write("Input 10 elements in the array :\n");
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("element - {0} : ", i);
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }            

            Console.Write("\nElements in array are: ");
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}  ", arr[i]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try breaking your issues into pieces and asking local questions. Search by 'How to parse string to int' and 'How to write switch statement with int/string options' would bring you results much faster when compared to full problem analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:
using System;

```
namespace ASortAboveTheRest { 
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainMenu();
        }

        static void MainMenu()
        {    
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose a sort algorithm to perform on the Array");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 1: Heap Sort");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 2: Bubble Sort");
            Console.WriteLine("Option 3: Shell Sort");

            Console.WriteLine("Please type: 1, 2, or 3");
            // Take Option input as an INT
            int myOption;
            myOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] arr = new int[10];
            int i;
            Console.Write("Input 10 elements in the array :\n");
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("element - {0} : ", i);
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.Write("\nElements in array are: ");
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}  ", arr[i]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            
            //Use switch case after taking array input from the user
            switch(myOption) {
            case 1:
                //Call Heap Sort Function and pass your array
                break;
            case 2:
                // Call Bubble Sort Function and pass your array
                break;
            case 3:
                //Call Shell Sort Function and pass your array
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, Sourabh, I was working with the switch but my knowledge on switches was a bit rust and so when the Heapsort uses an parameter in the public void heapSort(int[] arr), I was trying to pass that into the switch like this: case "1":
            //        HeapSort.heapSort(int[] arr);
            //        break;

Comment: I would also suggest to check the ```Console.ReadLine()``` for being an integer. Otherwise, your code will fail on 'a' letter typed.

Comment: Nice suggestion but it will not "fail" as `Convert.ToInt32` will convert 'a' to `ASCII` and the default switch case will break. Technically what you are doing in your answer is the correct way to go i.e. if the option is invalid then re-read the option from the user. 
Good find.

Answer (score 1):

You shall:

1. read the option as a string and then try to parse it, handling the mistake of conversion
2. also handle cases when a user enters a number that doesn't match your options
3. rule of thumb: never use 'if' you can use 'switch', never used 'switch' if the mapping can be specified as a dictionary

```
string optionTyped = Console.ReadLine();
int sortOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var sortFunctions = new Dictionary<int, Func<int[], int[]>>
    {
        { 1, HeapSort },
        { 2, BubbleSort },
        { 3, ShellSort }
    };
    
while(!Int32.TryParse(optionTyped, out sortOption)
      or (!sortFunctions.Keys.Contains(sortOption)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid option, try again.");
    optionTyped = Console.ReadLine();
}

Func<int[], int[]> sort = sortFunctions[sortOption]
...
int[] resultArray = sort(inputArray)
```